# Aftermath of the destruction of the Ring

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

Were there any major events or stories that happened after the destruction of the Ring or was that the final storyline of Tolkien?

Comment: Have you read the Appendices to the Return of the King?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The New Shadow](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Shadow) was written as an early Fourth Age tale, but Tolkien abandoned it before it got very far.

> I did begin a story placed about 100 years after the Downfall, but it proved both sinister and depressing. Since we are dealing with Men, it is inevitable that we should be concerned with the most regrettable feature of their nature: their quick satiety with good. So that the people of Gondor in times of peace, justice and prosperity, would become discontented and restless — while the dynasts descended from Aragorn would become just kings and governors — like Denethor or worse. I found that even so early there was an outcrop of revolutionary plots, about a centre of secret Satanistic religion; while Gondorian boys were playing at being Orcs and going around doing damage. I could have written a 'thriller' about the plot and its discovery and overthrow — but it would have been just that. Not worth doing.

(Letter 256)

The text, so far as it went, is published in History of Middle Earth 12 (The Peoples of Middle Earth).

Answer (score 1):

Gandalf and most of the elves sailed west, men dominated the earth and the [Fourth Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Age) Began.

Tolkien also kinda sorta intended his works to be a sort English mythology which took place on earth, so I guess you can say that all real history is also part of of the Tolkien storyline